# Accessing locaitonManager from both AppDelegate and ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

In my app delegate class, I am declaring locaitonManager:

`var locationManager: CLLocationManager?`

Later in my app inside one of the view controller classes, I need to stop location updates:

`locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()`

But I get error:

> Value of type CLLocation Manager.... has no member ....

because view controller cannot access the location manager declared inside app delegate class. What is my simple way out? I have to have locationManager access in app delegate.

**Note:** Strangely, my 
`func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`
is inside the view controller too, and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: The delegate method will be called on the view controller if you have set the view controller as the delegate. You can get a reference to the application delegate using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`

Comment: Nice, I will try this when I get back to this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question for future reference:

In ViewController's class:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Then later in the code I am able to refer to the locationManager declared in App Delegate like this:

```
appDelegate.locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Swift 3: 
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate